# Matlab Importdata Precision

Tags: matlab, file-io, precision, data-import

I'm trying to use importdata for several data files containing data of a precision up to 11 digits after the decimal, is Matlab seems to think I am only interested in the first 5 digits when using importdata, is there an alternative method I could use to load my data, or a method to define the precision to which I want my data loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try:

```
format long g
```

Also, can you paste some of the data you are trying to load?